# Resuming debugger: error during debugging loop: TypeError: firstViewRangeElement is null

Tags: xpages

I really don't know why firebug showing this error, when previewing the xpages 8.5.2 mobile controls in Firefox

"Resuming debugger: error during debugging loop: TypeError: firstViewRangeElement is null"

Please let me know if you have any idea to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also run into this error when I added a "debugger" keyword to my javascript file. This is intercepted by firebug AND firefox's internal debugger at the same time. I think this is what caused the error for me.

Comment: I downgraded my Firefox from beta to stable release and issue resolved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a Firebug error (and not an error related to XPages), I believe.

Try a search on Google for "Resuming debugger: error during debugging loop".

Comment: I downgraded my Firefox from beta to stable release and issue resolved.